# Search Display Controller does not show searchBar

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller, searchbar

I created a simple TableViewController using the template offered by xCode.
Then I open the xib file of the TableViewController with Interface Builder and I drag/add a uisearchdisplaycontroller on the top part of the tableView.
xCode automatically creates and link all the outlets.
I save the xib file and I run the app but the searchBar is not displayed!

What else should I do to make appear the searchBar?!?

THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!

Comment: My comment won't answer your question. But I think you should try coding without Interface Builder (it's the devil ^^), you will then better understand when something is not working. I think you forget something to add in the code, but as I never used IB, I can't answer ^^

Comment: Interface Builder is not the devil. It definitely has its place. Its not the answer for everything, but some things are very much easier.

Answer (score 3):

I was having this exact issue. I would drag the search bar, it would "snap" into place on the table as a header, but it would never show.

I found that when you are presenting the next View you need to initWithNibName:

Example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewSubclass *dvc = [[UITableViewSubclass alloc] initWithNibName:@"UITableViewSubclass" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
    [dvc release];
}
```

This is also assuming you dragged the SearchDisplayController into the xib file. It will do all the necessary connections for you.

Hope that helps.